# How to check if an item exist in a dynamic array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, match, shopping-cart

I want to add Items to cartArray. If Array has already an item , I m going to write a function which prevents it adding it again by just increasing its quantity.. How can it be possible. Array  Item has more than one element(e.g.id,price,quantity).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cartArray = []; //array of cart Items data
    var total = 0;
    var shipping = 2;

    $(".addToCart").click(function(){

               var flag = 0;
        //Get all data of item to be added
            var id= $(this).data("id");
            var price= $(this).data("price");
            var image = $(this).data('image');
            var name = $(this).data("name");
            var quantity = $(this).data("quantity");
            var availability = $(this).data("availability");
            var weight = $(this).data("weight");


            //check if cart is empty to remove empty cart view
               if( (cartArray.length === 0) ) { 
                $("#empty-cart").css("display","none");}

        //Traverse the cart list to check if item already exists or not
             for(var i = 0; i < cartArray.length; ++i){
                 if (//what to do here to match id){
                 var increment= $( this ).find(".quantity").val();
                  increment++;
                  flag = 1;
                  $( this ).find(".quantity").val(increment);
                    return false;
                   }
                 }

          //Add new Item in cart
              if(flag == 0){
                  var cartItem =  "<li class='newItem'><p class='id'>"+id+"</p><div class='picture'><img src='"+image+"' ></div> <div class='details'><p class='name'>"+name+"</p><span class='weight'>"+weight+"</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>"+availability+"</span><p class='price'>"+price+"</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value="+quantity+" ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>"
                     cartArray.push(cartItem);
                     localStorage.setItem('cartItem',JSON.stringify(cartArray)); 
                      var getItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));
                     // $("#cartList").prepend(cartItem);
                    $("#cartList li .id").css('display','none');
                      console.log("Item Added")
                   //increment in badge icon number when new item added in cart
                      var counterInc = parseInt($(".badge").html()) + 1;
                        $(".badge").html(counterInc);
                 }
})
```

Comment: The challenge here is that you are storing your cart items as the HTML string they render on the page.  _Ideally_ you would be storing the cart contents as objects containing the salient information, which would make it much easier to fetch and manipulate that information.  Is this sort of refactor an option for you?  Or is this approach of storing markup strings necessary for some reason?

Comment: I have to do it in this way like I am storing new Items in HTML string, Is it possible to filter data of items from local storage or not?

Comment: It _is_, but it will be much more difficult to do it from HTML strings.  If you stored the data itself, you could filter much more easily and also render from the stored data using some sort of template/factory function.  To do it with HTML strings you'll have to search for "[magic strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings)," which is not a robust solution and could lead to problems, or you'll have to render first to get an attribute; this is why I am wondering if refactoring is possible.

Comment: If I store data in objects , how would I style the cart Items?

Comment: Whenever I add Items to cart I have to make an html DOM element dynamically, How can I do it without creating DOM elements and storing only data itself?

Comment: [Here is a fiddle that illustrates by example how to store data only and render from that using a helper function](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/6oqu08eg/26/).  Note that I deviate from your example in that I use a fake `localStorage` implementation and an object instead of an array; however, the basics are the same.  `addItemToCart` adds an object that stores the data only for the items, and calls a function called `updateCartUi`, which empties the current cart element of children then redraws the cart from the current data using `drawCartItem` to render each entry. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT

after Alexander's comment you have to modify the solution

```js
function isInCart(id){
 var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('actualCart'));
 return !!items.filter(i=>i.id == id).length;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var actualCartArray = []; //array of cart Items data
    var cartArray = []; //array of cart Items html
    var total = 0;
    var shipping = 2;

    $(".addToCart").click(function(){
      if(isInCart($(this).data("id"))){
        return;
      }
               var flag = 0;
        //Get all data of item to be added
            var id= $(this).data("id");
            var price= $(this).data("price");
            var image = $(this).data('image');
            var name = $(this).data("name");
            var quantity = $(this).data("quantity");
            var availability = $(this).data("availability");
            var weight = $(this).data("weight");
           actualCartArray.push({id,price,image,name,quantity,availability,weight});

            //check if cart is empty to remove empty cart view
               if( (cartArray.length === 0) ) { 
                $("#empty-cart").css("display","none");}

        //Traverse the cart list to check if item already exists or not
             for(var i = 0; i < cartArray.length; ++i){
                 if (//what to do here to match id){
                 var increment= $( this ).find(".quantity").val();
                  increment++;
                  flag = 1;
                  $( this ).find(".quantity").val(increment);
                    return false;
                   }
                 }

          //Add new Item in cart
              if(flag == 0){
                  var cartItem =  "<li class='newItem'><p class='id'>"+id+"</p><div class='picture'><img src='"+image+"' ></div> <div class='details'><p class='name'>"+name+"</p><span class='weight'>"+weight+"</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>"+availability+"</span><p class='price'>"+price+"</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' value="+quantity+" ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>"
                     cartArray.push(cartItem);
                     localStorage.setItem('cartItem',JSON.stringify(cartArray));
localStorage.setItem('actualCart',JSON.stringify(actualCartArray));  
                      var getItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));
                     // $("#cartList").prepend(cartItem);
                    $("#cartList li .id").css('display','none');
                      console.log("Item Added")
                   //increment in badge icon number when new item added in cart
                      var counterInc = parseInt($(".badge").html()) + 1;
                        $(".badge").html(counterInc);
                 }
})
```

Create and use a function as the following. You pass an id and returns boolean if the item is in localStorage cart or not.

```js
function isInCart(id){
 var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));
 return !!items.filter(i=>i.id == id).length;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good solution if they were storing the data objects in the array and stringifying them to store in localStorage-- however, if you look at the condition under `//Add new Item in cart`, you see what they are storing is actually the string of the markup they intend to render in the UI.